# How to put gap for toggle image and hint text in Edittext android?

Tags: java, android, jquery, xml

I am new for android. i want space gap between toggle image and hint text same field of edit text

[image: this is image for edittext].

This is my edit text xml code

```
     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_flag"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:hint="Nationality"/>
```

Comment: use `drawablePadding`

Comment: i want another help also. in this edittext possible to decrease the hint text darkness.

Comment: see both solution in answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution

> I want space gap between toggle image and hint text same field of edit
>   text

set **drawablePadding** `android:drawablePadding="15dp"`

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/nation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/email"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_flag"
android:drawablePadding="15dp"
android:hint="Nationality"
android:inputType="textCapWords" />
```

> in this edittext possible to decrease the hint text darkness

You can set **hint color** programmatically

```
editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_gray));
```

Comment: i want another help also, in app bar title how to align center?

Comment: Don't mind but this are the basic things. first you should search on google.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
android:drawablePadding="20dp"
```

to change Hint text color use:

```
android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/nation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_flag"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:hint="Nationality"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use the drawablePadding property.

```
<EditText
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/nation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/email"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_flag"
android:hint="Nationality"
android:inputType="textCapWords" />
```